# Umgangssprachlicher Ausdruck für »Leute zu einem Getränk oder zu essen einladen«

Tags: phrase-request, colloquial

Was ist der umgangssprachliche Ausdruck für *Leute zu einem Getränk oder zu essen einladen*? Ich habe es schon wieder vergessen.

Answer (score 10):

Statt *jemandem etwas zu spendieren*/*jemanden zu etwas einladen* kann man umgangssprachlich auch *jemandem einen/etwas ausgeben*. Laut Duden ist *jemanden etwas/einen ausgeben* nicht spezifisch für Getränke ([Quelle](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/ausgeben#Bedeutung2b)), ich würde es im Alltag aber vorallem auf Getränke beziehen.

Beispiel:

> Was wollt ihr trinken? Ich geb' einen aus!
>
> Ich geb' die erste Runde Bier aus!

Answer (score 4):

Wenn es darum geht, im Restaurant oder in einer Bar für andere zu bezahlen, kann man auch sagen:

> Die Getränke gehen auf mich!
>
> Das Essen geht auf mich!
>
> Die erste Runde geht auf mich!

Comment: "etwas geht auf jemanden" ist nicht auf essen und trinken beschränkt, sondern auf bezahlen im Speziellen und Verantworlichkeit im Allgemeinen.

Answer (score 0):

Umgangssprachlich wird oft

> einen ausgeben

benutzt. Ganz unabhängig ob es sich um Speisen oder Getränke handelt.

Comment: Ist das nicht eher ein Kommentar auf meine Antwort?

Comment: kann man so oder so sehen. ich hab mich in dem Fall für eine eigene Antwort entschieden.